# Getting coordinates that are in sight based on current location and heading

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm currently stuck as I don't really know what to use as a search term on Google for this.
Let's say I retrieve the user's location and heading through a `CLLocationManager` and then want to calculate what coordinates are in the user's FOV - or if it's easier - check if a given coordinate is in the user's FOV.

How could I solve this? Any advice/links to documentation is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to specify a maximum distance and an angle. Then you can calculate if a coordinate is in the field of view by checking that the distance between the user and the point is within the specified maximum distance and that the angle between is within the specified region.

The wikipedia article on [Field of view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view#Conversions) gives a nice example for doing the calculations.